# Calling Contract Function

Tags: web3js, react

I am trying to call a function from my back-end to my front-end. I know that my contract is deploying, however, I don't think my function is not being called correctly. My code is provided below. Does anyone know how I could fix this? Help would be insanely appreciated!

Comment: `I don't think my function is not being called correctly` - so you think that it IS being called correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since function `createChallenge` changes the state of your contract, you should execute it with `send` instead of `call` (similarly to how you deploy your contract):

```
this.GameChangerInstance.methods.createChallenge("name", "description", 10, 10).send({
    from: account,
    gas: ...
}).then((receipt) => {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**let contractInstance=new web3.eth.Contract(abi,"contract address",{from:accounts[0]});
 
contractInstance.function();**

Hey there :)

I'm using this to interact with a contract with contracts throw web3js with my frnt-end.
P.S:acocunts[0] is just the main account .
Hope help you!